# list-style: none lightbox is not working?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

So there's an issue.
If you view this .htm page you see that image. 
http://icpy.webs.com/text/Mass.htm
The problem is originally there was a bullet decorator which was the `list-style`. The lightbox image was working. When I applied the `List-style-type: none`, my image wasn't working when I clicked on it. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Your HTML is broken, do some efforts with validation first - http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: That code you linked is a bit scary - you're going to need to fix your code quite a bit before being able to hunt for these errors.

Comment: Also be very careful with capitalization in the CSS code - that can be enough to break your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html is all messed up.

```
<div id="cas> <ul> <li><a class=" title="Mass Sale layouts" href="#inlineframe" fancybox"="">
   <img src="http://dgamerhelp.webs.com/soccer/layouts/BEA01.png">
   <div id="inlineframe" style="width:1040px;height:785px;display: none;">
</div>
```

1. Close the id tag of div like :  div **id="cas"**
2. Close the `<li>` tag
3. Close the `<ul>` tag
4. Close the main div correctly.
5. If you are not using a class for `<a>` tag, then remove it completely ( `<a class="` )

Fixing the above things should solve your issue. Im surprised, it actually worked first time..

Cleaned up code should look something like this :

```
<div id="cas"> 
    <ul> 
        <li>
            <a class="" title="Mass Sale layouts" href="#inlineframe" fancybox"=">
                <img src="http://dgamerhelp.webs.com/soccer/layouts/BEA01.png">
                <div id="inlineframe" style="width:1040px;height:785px;display: none;">Whatever that needs to go here.
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>    
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have javascript errors on that page, which will prevent it from working.

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://icpy.webs.com/text/.http://icpy.webs.com/fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"
```